# How to get last n commit of git repo using the https github link of a particular branch

Tags: git, github

I have tried using the following command but I got only the last commit
`git ls-remote --heads https://github.com/xxxxxxxx refs/heads/main`

Comment: Are you asking for `git log <repo>`?

Comment: For doing that you already need to be inside the cloned repo. I want to be able to do it only from the repo link

Comment: How about [Getting remote git commit log without local copy](https://superuser.com/q/341441/1095685)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-api%5D+list+commits